# html (dropdown) select option and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [append option to select menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182772/append-option-to-select-menu)
>   [how do I add an option to a html form dropdown list with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992261/how-do-i-add-an-option-to-a-html-form-dropdown-list-with-javascript)

I have a html select element like below

```
<form>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I would like to add another option value like below using javascript(not jQuery)

```
<option>Berry</option>
```

Can anyone say how could I do that ??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First grab the select using `document.getElementById`

```
var sel = document.getElementById('mySelect');
```

Then add the option to the select's `options` collection like this

```
sel.options.add(new Option('text', 'val'));
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/SX5b3/)

Comment: I am looking for a solution like you.But your's one is not working in my form.What could be problem ?? I saw your jsfiddle.

Comment: is there any event handler required ??

Comment: @php - no event handler needed.  Not sure what the problem is - just take a hard look at the fiddle and see if you can surmise what you did wrong.

Comment: it seems funny to me. I paste my code to your fiddle and it is working. But in my application it is not working.

Comment: I am also trying like below 
 
`<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

var sel = document.getElementById('mySelect');
sel.options.add(new Option('text', 'val'));

</script>

</head>

<body>
<form>
    <select id="mySelect">
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Pear</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>Orange</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>`  

but it is also not working.

Comment: @php - Ahh - your script is running before your Dom is ready.  Move your script block to the bottom of your page's body.

Comment: But I would like to use that before body. How can I do that ??

Comment: You just need to **define** the script at the end of your body.  That's all.  There's no reason you'd need to use the script before your body is defined - in fact that won't work, since the dom elements are not yet ready.  Just put the script at the very very end of your body and everything should work right.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Declare some variables
var ctn = "Berry",
    opt = document.createElement("option");

//Set the text
opt.innerText = ctn;

//Put it in
document.getElementById('mySelect').appendChild(opt);
```

LIVE demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/BzZXn/

This can also apply to all HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x=document.getElementById("mySelect");
var option=document.createElement("option");
option.text="Kiwi";
try{
  // for IE earlier than version 8
  x.add(option,x.options[null]);
}
catch (e){
  x.add(option,null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function fnc()
{
document.getElementById("mySelect").options.add(new Option('berry'));
}
</script>

<form>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="fnc()" />
</form>
```