# Add item to dropdown list in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this JavaScript+HTML to populate a dropdown menu but it is not working, am i doing anything wrong? Note I want the drop down menu to be filled on page Load

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function addList(){
    var select = document.getElementById("year");
    for(var i = 2011; i >= 1900; --i) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = option.value = i;
    select.add(option, 0);
      }
     }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

       <select id="year" name="year"></select>
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I add an option to a html form dropdown list with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992261/how-do-i-add-an-option-to-a-html-form-dropdown-list-with-javascript)

Comment: @HashemQolami I do not have a button and hence I am confused on where to put the function.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since your script is in `<head>`, you need to wrap it in `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var select = document.getElementById("year");
    for(var i = 2011; i >= 1900; --i) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = i;
        select.add(option, 0);
    }
};
```

You can also do it in this way

```
<body onload="addList()">
```

Answer (score 16):

For higher performance, I recommend this:

```
var select = document.getElementById("year");
var options = [];
var option = document.createElement('option');

//for (var i = 2011; i >= 1900; --i)
for (var i = 1900; i < 2012; ++i)
{
    //var data = '<option value="' + escapeHTML(i) +'">" + escapeHTML(i) + "</option>';
    option.text = option.value = i;
    options.push(option.outerHTML);
}

select.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', options.join('\n'));
```

This avoids a redraw after each appendChild, which speeds up the process considerably, especially for a larger number of options.

Optional for generating the string by hand:

```
function escapeHTML(str)
{
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var text = document.createTextNode(str);
    div.appendChild(text);
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

However, I would not use these kind of methods at all. 
It seems crude. You best do this with a documentFragment:

```
var docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 1900; i < 2012; ++i)
{
     docfrag.appendChild(new Option(i, i));
}

var select = document.getElementById("year");
select.appendChild(docfrag);
```

Comment: How about if I just want to replace the value instead of appending? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/appendChild) method:

```
select.appendChild(option);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddItem()
    {
        // Create an Option object       
        var opt = document.createElement("option");        

        // Assign text and value to Option object
        opt.text = "New Value";
        opt.value = "New Value";

        // Add an Option object to Drop Down List Box
        document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList.ClientID%>').options.add(opt);
    }
<script />
```

The Value will append to the drop down list.

Comment: This actually worked! The other examples did not. Thank you! (implementation here:)

if ($("#MainContent_ddlFilterFieldKey").val() == "Date Time") {// Create an Option object       
              var opt = document.createElement("option");        

              // Assign text and value to Option object
              opt.text = "New Value";
              opt.value = "New Value";

              // Add an Option object to Drop Down List Box
              document.getElementById('MainContent_ddlFilterBooleanOption').options.add(opt);

          }

Answer (score 0):

i think you have only defined the function. you are not triggering it anywhere.

please do

```
window.onload = addList();
```

or trigger it on some other event

after its definition

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mithunsatheesh/PzCEN/)