# CRM 2013 Create an input field in webresource based on optionset field

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

For my HTML webresource I'm retrieving the value of an optionset field via XrmServiceToolkit.

```
XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.RetrieveMultiple("tisa_qualitycontrolassessmentSet", "?$select=tisa_questionscore", 
  function(results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var tisa_questionscore = results[i].tisa_questionscore;
    }
  }, 
  function(error) {
    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
  }, 
  function() {
    //On Complete - Do Something
  }, 
  false
);
```

There is no problem. Now I need to add into my HTML page a dropdown input field with the selected value from my query and show a list(dropdown) with the rest of the options of my optionSetValue. The values of the field can be 0 - NO, 1 - Yes and null.

Which is the best practice to create this input field?

Comment: are you looking for this - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query the particular OptionSet metadata from CRM & populate the values in your HTML dropdown, the below web api can be used to get them. [Read more](https://carldesouza.com/getting-local-option-set-metadata-with-webapi-javascript/)

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='account')/Attributes/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.PicklistAttributeMetadata?$select=LogicalName&$filter=LogicalName eq 'new_fieldname'&$expand=OptionSet
```

**Edit**: I realized later that you're using CRM 2013, so web api won't be available for you. You have to use `SDK.Metadata.js` like explained in [this blog](http://mscrmtechie.blogspot.com/2015/11/retrieve-option-set-text-from-crm.html).

Then from the response, you can iterate & add the `<option>` to `<select>` control in HTML like explained in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10992261/7920473)